# How to change regex to handle _ symbol after a number?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to have a regex that can match the following names:

`Standard_DS1_v2`
`Standard_DS2_v2`
`...`
`Standard_DS15_v2`

`Standard_DS1`
`Standard_DS2`
`...`
`Standard_DS14`

`Standard_GS1`
`Standard_GS2`
`...`
`Standard_GS5`

Now I have the following regex:

```
private const string PremiumStorageRoleSizesRegex = @"^Standard_((DS)|(GS))\d+$";

machineSizeMetadatas = machineSizeMetadatas.Where(metadata => Regex.IsMatch(metadata.Name, PremiumStorageRoleSizesRegex));
```

But I don't know how to handle the first sequence (`Standard_DS1_v2`).

How can I change my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an optional group:

```
^Standard_(DS|GS)\d+(?:_v\d+)?$
                    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or a simpler `^Standard_[DG]S\d+(?:_v\d+)?$` to avoid alternation group. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5EStandard_(DS%7CGS)%5Cd%2B(%3F%3A_v%5Cd%2B)%3F%5Cr%3F%24&i=Standard_DS15_v2%0D%0AStandard_DS14%0D%0AStandard_GS1%0D%0AStandard_DS1_v2&o=m)

You may add a capturing group wherever you need.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `Standard_` - a literal `Standard_` substring
- `(DS|GS)` - either a `DS` or `GS` string (you may replace it with `[DG]S`)
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(?:_v\d+)?` - 1 or 0 (=optional) sequences of `_` + `v` + `1 or more digits
- `$` - end of string.